# Batch access to NetBIOS locations / associated script

Tags: batch-file, network-share, netbios

I'm trying to write a batch file to

- Access \sharelocation\folder\file
- Compare that file to c:\folder\file
- If the files are the same, run the local file.
- If the files are different, replace the local file and run the new local file.

I'm stuck on the first part.  Is there a good way to do this?

Maybe I can use `net` to map the share to a fixed letter if not already mapped then use `fc /b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

- Mount the share, as per http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true:

  net use x: \share\location
- Compare the files

  fc c:\folder\file x:\folder\file
- Branch as necessary, as per this SOq - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671642/how-can-i-compare-two-files-in-a-batch-file:

  if errorlevel 1 goto filesDiffer
  goto noDifferences
- Unmount the share:

  net use x: \share\location /delete

The whole script should be:

```
net use x: \\share\location
fc c:\folder\file x:\folder\file
if errorlevel 1 goto filesDiffer
:noDifferences
echo Do something when there are no differences
goto theEnd

:filesDiffer
echo Do something when there are differences

:theEnd
net use x: \\share\location /delete
```

Note you would have issues if x: is already mapped on the target machine. Use `fc /b` for binary comparison.